# How do I share my C/C++ project and hide some of the source code?

Tags: c++, c, unix, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to share my project which was written in C/C++ (Linux environment gcc/g++ compiler) as shared library/static library without actually sharing the source code. So that other users can use my project without actually knowing my source code. Can anyone tell how do I share it as .so/.a format?

Suppose, my project looks like:

**main.cpp**,
**source1.cpp**,
**source2.cpp**,
**source3.cpp**,
**head1.h**,
**Makefile**

How can I share this project by hiding the source code of the files **source1.cpp**, **source2.cpp** and **source3.cpp** and making these as shared library/static library. **main.cpp** file contains the     main()     function. What is the detailed procedure?

PS: I am a novice in shared library/static library.

Comment: What are the minimum things (such as header files etc.) do I need to share? Can you give a simple example of it?

Comment: For it to be of any use, you'll need to have public header files that expose the essential functionality that your library offers. All other details can be hidden in precompiled binaries

Comment: Does `main.cpp` have a `main` function?  If so, it can't be part of your library.

Comment: Yes, it contains the main function.

Comment: If you have a `main` then its not a library, its a program.

Comment: @cdarke main.cpp is not the library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose you have the following source file:

mylib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_print(int i)
{
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
}
```

The public header for this would be:

mylib.h:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

void my_print(int i);

#endif
```

You could then build the library like this:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -c mylib.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -shared -fPIC -o libmylib.so mylib.o
```

Then you can distribute libmylib.so and mylib.h to users.  Then can then use it in their code like this:

user_prog.c:

```
#include "mylib.h"

int main()
{
    my_print(5);
    return 0;
}
```

They would then put libmylib.so into someplace like /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib, and compile like this:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o user_prog user_prog.c -l mylib
```

For your particular case, assuming head1.h contains the public interface and source1.cpp source2.cpp source3.cpp the library, you would compile like this:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -c source1.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -c source2.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -c source3.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -shared -fPIC -o libmylib.so source1.o source2.o source3.o
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, the generated shared object     libmylib.so    will be machine dependent/compiler version dependent?

Comment: @thesukantadey It will be machine / OS dependent.  For example, if you compile on Linux x86_64, you can link / run on any Linux x86_64.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And how do I share the above-mentioned sources as a static library (.a file)?

Comment: To share the sources, create a tar.Z that contains them. Look up the tar command and the compress command.

Comment: @FredK I don't want to share the source codes but as a library.

Comment: I assumed that when you said " And how do I share the above-mentioned sources" that you meant just that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create object files from your source files. Then create static and/or shared libraries. You will need to provide a header file for use with your library. And note that your library must NOT contain main().

See [detailed instructions for gcc](http://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/GCC/create-libraries/index)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can. Simply supply the people with the library file and the header files corresponding to the source files used to build the library.